# Check if Argument is instanceof specified generic type

Tags: java, generics, parameters

Ok, so say I have a class:

```
public class Example<E extends Something> {

public Something s;
public E e;

public Example(E e, Something s) {
    this.e = e;
    this.s = s;
}

}
```

and in another class I have:

```
public Something a = new ExtendsSomething();
public Something b = new AlsoExtendsSomething();
//Assume I have many more classes that also extend Something, so I cannot do instanceof
//for each class
public Example<ExtendsSomething> example1 = new Example<ExtendsSomething>(a);
public Example<ExtendsSomething> example2 = new Example<ExtendsSomething>(b);
```

What code would I write in the constructor to throw an error on line 6 of the second class, because b is not an instance of ExtendsSomething?

Comment: Nothing can extend String, because it's a `final` class, so your example generic bound of `<E extends String>` is nonsensical

Comment: and even if you were extending from something other than `String` I would also expect it to throw a compiler error anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I have now edited the question so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The very title of this question has the answer in it.

```
if(b instanceof ExtendsString)
{
    public Example<ExtendsString> example2 = new Example<ExtendsString>(b);
}
else
{
    //handle your error case
}
```

if that throws an error, maybe you have to cast `b`

```
if(b instanceof ExtendsString)
{
    public Example<ExtendsString> example2 = new Example<ExtendsString>((ExtendsString)b);
}
else
{
    //handle your error case
}
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity. Please look again.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will refuse to compile your example program because `Example`'s constructor takes two arguments. If you remove the `s` argument, then the compiler will reject the program because `b` is not a subclass of `ExtendsSomething`, just as you'd expect. You don't need to do anything additional in the constructor.